# Merge Information in two different datasourcs in ssis

Tags: merge, ssis, google-cloud-dataflow

I have two different datasource .lets say A which contains informations about customers :name ,city, divison(GUID) , a dtasource B which contains one columns namedivision(GUID).
my first datsource is returning more than one records and the second only one record(a specific divison that i should get dynamically).

Ineed to update the column divisio in the the data flow returned by the the first source by the value of the column namedivision returned by the second .

Comment: Excellent, so you're using SSIS to work with data in Google bigtables or are you working with google-cloud-dataflow as you've tagged?